# "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" POST JSON method in Insomnia

Tags: node.js, json, post, insomnia

I use for testing my project API Insomnia(like a Postman) program and when i use GET methods all going without problems, but POST method return undefined `req.body.name` and `req.body.price`,
this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcnIC.png) which i catch and this is my request
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP80u.png)

this is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config()


mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://vadim:${process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PS}@cluster0-abuqs.mongodb.net/shop`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/products', productRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

and this my router of products.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('../models/product')

router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    });
    product
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Handling POST requests to /products",
                createdProduct: result
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

and model of product.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the api receives an actual POST request? You can determine that by checking out the morgan logs. Also, I can recommend the usage of the `body-parser` plugin, which makes working with JSON bodies way easier and less painful. Have a look at it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use body-parser to catch data with POST method with express.

First, you need to install it:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then in your code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('../models/product');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

express.use(bodyParser.json());

express.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    });
    //The rest of your code
});
```

For more about it, [read the package docs](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: yes you right `express.use(bodyParser.json());` helped me, but i think `body-parser` now replace on `useNewUrlParser: true` i was wrong?

Comment: This is a mongodb issue with express. You need to add useNewUrlParser in mongo config. Check the answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316865/deprecated-body-parser

Comment: check plz my app.js i use `useNewUrlParser` in my `mongoose.connect`, but it doesn't work

Comment: I think that the mongo add data to database too soon. You need to add `.then()` after your connection then call the routes to ensure that the connection is successful before you proceed.